# How do I prevent further theft from my compromised Ethereum address?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

#### Background on the compromised address

I fell for a MEW phishing scam, and I use that particular eth address for airdrops, investments sites etc, I'm expecting eth to be paid to me through that address, and I can't change the address because I've already used it.

#### My approach

My intended approach is: a script that will perpetually check my address for any incoming ether, and automatically transfer it to another address. This needs to happen before the scammer transfers the ether out. I am willing to use a high gas price, so the transfer can be swiftly included in a block.

#### How to Implement?

From my little research, I've found out that this can only happen through webjs, and having the full eth node. Can I use infura and Nodejs to do this? If it's possible, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @sissy . Can you provide code for what you have attempted so far?
The description suggests that you are trying to swipe Emails to do with Etheruem transfers - could you possibly be doing this to modify the destinations?

Comment: Dragonthoughts nooo. Not that. I fell for a MEW phishing scam, and I use that particular eth address for airdrops, investments sites etc, I'm expecting eth to be paid to me through that address, and I can't change the address cos I've already used it. I want a script that will always be checking my address for any incoming eth, and automatically transfer it to another address once it enters so the scammer won't be able to take it. It's very urgent pls help me

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @sissy can you give an example where you "can't change the address because [you]'ve already used it"? I would expect any investment platform or token to have a feature to change withdrawal addresses or transfer the token.

Comment: If you have control of the mail service, you could set up a redirect or turn the email address into an alias. That would get allow you to route it without it ever touching your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

### Racing the Scammer

You are unlikely to be able to out-compete the scammer in a race to withdraw. They are "professionals" at this, and can probably submit the withdrawal transactions faster than you.

### Stop the Bleeding

Your best option is to find a way to change the location of any future dividends & withdrawals. For example, if you have an ERC20 token that sends you dividends (and the scammer didn't already drain the token from your account), then transfer that token to an uncompromised account. Dividends will start appearing in your new account, and the scammer cannot intercept them.

### Prevention

I'm sorry for your loss. Many people have learned expensive lessons this way. It's worth reading up on [prevention techniques to avoid phishing scams](https://medium.com/mycrypto/a-safer-mycrypto-79d65196e7d8), to help protect yourself in the future.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @zero298 The OP question is "How do I get my money before a scammer gets it" and the answer supplied is "You can't." It may not be in the spirit of what they wanted but it is exactly the advice that they need.

Comment: @Marie Sorry, I saw as such in the comments.  I added the detail from the comment to the question but forgot to remove my comment on your answer.

Comment: @zero298 Not my answer but I see, gotcha!